# Springboot app cannot connect to MongoDB container with docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker-compose

I've been fighting with this problem for weeks and still couldn't find what I'm doing wrong to be honest.

I have a basic springboot service supposed to connect MongoDB container. When I'm running the service locally (without Dockerised) it works fine but if I run the service and MongoDB in containers, I get MongoSocketOpenException with a connection refused.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:14-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
 idv-service:
 image: idv-service-img
 container_name: idv-service
 build: .
 hostname: idvservice
 #restart: on-failure
 ports:
  - 8091:8091
 depends_on:
  - mongodb
 networks:
  - gateway

mongodb:
 image: mongo:5.0
 hostname: mongodb
 container_name: idv-mongodb
 restart: unless-stopped
 ports:
  - 27011:27011
 volumes:
  - dbdata:/data/db
 networks:
  - gateway
 command: --bind_ip 0.0.0.0

volumes:
  dbdata:

networks:
  gateway:
  driver: bridge
```

and finally application.properties file

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongodb
spring.data.mongodb.port=27011
spring.data.mongodb.database=ttm-idv-db
```

Logs from the container

```
idv-service    | 
idv-service    | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
idv-service    |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]
idv-service    |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:143) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]
idv-service    |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]
idv-service    |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]
idv-service    |        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
idv-service    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
idv-service    |        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
idv-service    |        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:589) ~[na:na]
idv-service    |        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
idv-service    |        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
idv-service    |        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333) ~[na:na]
idv-service    |        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648) ~[na:na]
idv-service    |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]
idv-service    |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]
idv-service    |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]
idv-service    |        ... 4 common frames omitted
idv-service    | 
idv-service    | 2021-08-25 12:38:00.425  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
idv-service    | 2021-08-25 12:38:00.440  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.m.t.a.idv.IdvServiceApplication        : Started IdvServiceApplication in 3.433 seconds (JVM running for 4.093)
```

Any clue on what I might be doing wrong?

Docker Engine: 20.10.8
Compose: 1.29.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your port mapping is incorrect. The Mongo container will listen to 27017 by default, so when you publish port 27011 on the Docker host, you need to map the 27011 host port to the 27017 container port, i.e.

```
ports: 
 - 27011:27017
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like I found the way to resolve it

```
mongodb:
    image: mongo:5.0
    hostname: mongodb
    container_name: idv-mongodb
    restart: unless-stopped
    #network_mode: "bridge"
   # environment:
    #  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
     # MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
    ports:
      - 27011:27011
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db
   # command: --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
    command: mongod --port 27011
```

The last line "command: mongod --port 27011" apparently enforces MongoDB to start listening on a different port. My thought was that it's handled by Docker container to map mongod service binding to given port in docker-compose file however turns out it's not true.